# сортировка массива структур с помощью qsort

Tags: c, сортировка, qsort

Народ прошу помощи, нужно отсортировать массив структур с помощью функции qsort()

```
        typedef struct word {
          int count;
          char *Word;
        }WORD;

    int cmpword_alpha(WORD *, WORD *)
    int cmpword_quant(WORD *, WORD *)


    int main(void)
    {
     .....

      qsort(words, totalw, sizeof(WORD *), (int (*)(const void *, const void *))cmpword_quant );
      //вывод отсортированного массива

      qsort(words, totalw, sizeof(WORD *), (int (*)(const void *, const void *))cmpword_alpha );
      //вывод отсортированного массива

}

    cmpword_alpha(WORD *w1, WORD *w2)
    {
       ;
      ///??что здесь писать???///
    }


    cmpword_quant(WORD *w1, WORD *w2)
    {
       ;
      ///??что здесь писать???///
    }
```

уже как только не пробовал, либо ошибка, либо сортирует непонятно как...

Comment: `int main(void)`, а не `main()`. Также, вот уже за эту клоунаду `(int (*)(const void *, const void *))cmpword_quant` - надо больно давать по рукам. Кстати, почему в приведенных огрызках кода не видно, что такое `words`? `sizeof(WORD *)` в списке аргументов как бы намекает, что это у вас массив указателей... Тогда все ясно. Ваши функции сравнения будут получать *указатель на указатель*.

Comment: да забыл указать WORD *words[10000];

Comment: так как быть? я пока только учусь и не совсем понимаю как эта функция работает, а как вы выразились клаунаду мне уже предоставили в таком виде....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Функции сравнения для `qsort` в С всегда пишутся с параметрами типа `const void *`

  ```
  int cmpword_alpha(const void *p1, const void *p2)
  {
    ...
  }
  ```

  а уж внутри этой функции вы будете преобразовывать параметры к правильному типу (см. ниже). При использовании этой функции в `qsort` теперь не надо делать никакого приведения типа к `(int (*)(const void *, const void *))`

  ```
  qsort(words, totalw, sizeof *words, cmpword_alpha);
  ```

  Дикий хак, когда функция сравнения пишется с типизированными параметрами, а затем силой приводится к `(int (*)(const void *, const void *))` оставьте "пионэрам-хакерам".
- Функция сравнения получает указатель на элемент сортируемого массива. Если ваш массив содержит элементы типа `WORD *`, то в функцию сравнения будет фактически приходить `WORD **` - указатель на указатель. Вот это вам и надо помнить, то есть внутри вашей функции сравнения следует поступать примерно так

  ```
  int cmpword_alpha(const void *p1, const void *p2)
  {
    WORD **pw1 = p1, **pw2 = p2;
    WORD *w1 = *pw1, *w2 = *pw2;

    // А теперь сравниваем слова по указателям `w1` и `w2`
    // Например: return strcmp(w1->Word, w2->Word);
  }
  ```

  или лучше

  ```
  int cmpword_alpha(const void *p1, const void *p2)
  {
    const WORD *const *pw1 = p1, *const *pw2 = p2;
    const WORD *w1 = *pw1, *w2 = *pw2;
    ...
  }
  ```

  Все это можно записать и в одну строчку без промежуточных переменных

  ```
    // WORD *w1 = *(WORD **) p1, *w2 = *(WORD **) pw2; 
    // или лучше
    const WORD *w1 = *(const WORD *const *) p1, *w2 = *(const WORD *const *) pw2;
  ```

  но это уже как вам больше нравится.
- Не указывать тип возвращаемого значения функции в языке С уже давно не разрешается. Поэтому не `cmpword_alpha(...`, а `int cmpword_alpha(...` и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, выручил, указатель на указатель для меня это как то пока немного сложно, но будем учиться, ещё раз спасибо что помогли)